# dplyr not working when calling group_by on a column of states

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe named election.raw with the following form:

[image]

now I am interested in grouping the dataframe by state so if I run the following command:

```
election.raw%>%group_by(state)
```

I get the following output:
[image]

[image]

As is apparent the states were not grouped by, I essentially want all the states to be together and then from there be able to declare the candidate that received the most votes per state and get a dataframe that shows the winner for each state. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a grouping, but that grouping won't change the dataframe unless  you do some summary to it.  Since you haven't provided anything reproduceable, here's a small example.

```
df <- data.frame(
  state = c('AZ','AZ','AZ','ID','ID'),
  votes = c(10, 2, 4, 12, 23)
)
```

df:

```
  state votes
1    AZ    10
2    AZ     2
3    AZ     4
4    ID    12
5    ID    23
```

This will `filter` out and return the `max` `votes` for each `state`.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  filter(votes == max(votes))
```

new_df:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   state [2]
  state votes
  <chr> <dbl>
1 AZ       10
2 ID       23
```

If you wanted to know each percentage of the total votes per state...

```
percents <- df %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(`%Total` = round(votes/sum(votes), 2)) %>%
  arrange(state, desc(`%Total`))
```

percents:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   state [2]
  state votes `%Total`
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 AZ       10     0.62
2 AZ        4     0.25
3 AZ        2     0.12
4 ID       23     0.66
5 ID       12     0.34
```

Comment: why is this the case? also how would I be able to do the above but instead I took the total votes for each candidate and divided them by the total votes for each state, and returned the max of these values

Comment: `group_by` will essentially subset your data for summaries.  For instance, if you have voting data and you filter for the maximum votes, you will get one record in return: whatever value was highest.  If you apply `group_by(state)`, each record will fall into a `group` that is a part of the entire dataset.  Then if you filter for maximum votes, you should receive the record with the largest vote count *per group*, in this case `state` - you should get 50 records: the maximum vote count per state because of the grouping.

Comment: See added content. If you wanted only the largest `%Total` votes by state, you would add `filter(\`%Total\` == max(\`%Total\`))`

Comment: I was more so referring to the sum of the percentages that you outputted for each candidate so some sort of sum by candidate after this. is there something like that for r?

Comment: The sum of percentages by state and candidate wouldn't make sense.  If you're trying to find the percentage of the total votes cast over the entire US, you would probably go with a `group_by(candidate)`, and summarize that way. You can also have multiple fields in your grouping: `group_by(candidate, state)` etc.  If you're unsure of how to use a function, try placing a `?` in front to read up on what exactly is happening (Ex: `?group_by`)

Comment: thank you sincerely you were a great help

Answer (score 3):

> I essentially want all the states to be together

Re-ordering the rows of a data frame is what `arrange()` does. `group_by` doesn't make any visible changes, it just lets subsequent calls to other commands (mutate, filter, summarize, etc.) know to do things by group rather than on the whole data.

```
# this is what you need to show all the rows together for each state
df %>% arrange(state)
```

But of course, arranging is a little pointless if you are going to collapse each state to a single summary row...

To get the county with most votes per state, TTS's answer shows a nicely general version, but for the common use case of getting the max per group, you can use `slice_max`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(state) %>%
  slice_max(votes, n = 1)
```

Comment: interesting that makes a lot more sense now. Yeah arrange would seem trivial in this case thank you. what would be the best practice if I wanted to report the largest percentage of votes for each state after calculating candidate state votes over total state votes?

Comment: I edited with an example with the utility function `slice_max`. See TTS's answer for a more general approach.